# No module named owslib.wmts

Tags: python

I installed owslib through command line by:

```
pip install owslib
```

and it worked. But for some reason I am getting an error saying: No module named owslib.wmts . What do you think would be causing this? I tried installing Anaconda, I've rebooted a few times, and when I run this script:

```
import pip
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
     for i in installed_packages])
print(installed_packages_list)
```

it shows me the installed modules like this:

```
['nose==1.3.7', 'numpy==1.11.1', 'overpy==0.3.1', 'owslib==0.11.2',
'pip==8.1.1', 'pyproj==1.9.5.1', 'python-dateutil==2.5.3', 
'pytz==2016.6.1', 'requests==2.11.1', 'setuptools==20.10.1', 'six==1.10.0']
```

any ideas?

Comment: It's not obvious from your question, where or how you are you getting an error.  The output above shows you have owslib installed, so you should be able to access owslib.wmts, what are the steps you take to get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am 99% sure this is a problem on my work machine. I have found a workaround by using the Anaconda terminal instead of windows cmd line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try 
    pip install owslib.wmts
Otherwise there might be a problem within the module. Look at this website it has the documentation for owslib [documentation](https://geopython.github.io/OWSLib/)